# NSDate is wrong when doing 'dateFromString'

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Im here in the UK and when working with dates in iOS they are always out by one hour (one hour behind), what I need is the correct time from an NSDate. Ive done the following, but i get two different times:

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

 NSLog(@"NSDate %@",today);
 NSLog(@"Time %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]);
 NSDate*stringDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
 NSLog(@"Time date %@",stringDate);
```

Here is what is logged:

```
NSDate 2015-07-01 16:07:22 +0000
Time 2015-07-01 17:07:22
Time date 2015-07-01 16:07:22 +0000
```

Why is this happening? Am i missing something obvious? Surely if the string date is correct, then doing `dateFromString` should yield the correct results?

The reason I need an `NSDate` is so I can get the correct amount of seconds using `[myTime timeIntervalSince1970]`

```
2015-07-01 17:07:22 //is the correct date
```

Im expecting an NSDate object that is correct to my date and time.

***Update***
**The answers below helped me find where I was going wrong, so I changed my approach, I was able to get the current timestamp doing the following:**

```
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *curdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
    int unix_timestamp =  [curdate timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSDate* referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 0];
    NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    int offset = (int)[timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate: referenceDate];
    int currentTimestamp = unix_timestamp + offset;

    NSLog(@"CUrrent time stamp %d",currentTimestamp);
```

Comment: Is your system time zone +0? You're not printing out the two dates the same way, so you wouldn't necessarily expect them to look the same.

Comment: @jtbandes its UTC/GMT+1

Comment: @jtbandes I updated my code to include more the NSDate prior.

Comment: Everything is correct here, `16:00 GMT+0` == `17:00 GMT+1`. What did you expect?

Comment: @hamstergene I expected string date to be the same as [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today], am I misunderstanding? I need an NSDate that is correct to my timezone so i thought this would be a workaround

Comment: The date dormatter defaults to the local timezone. If you want a different rimezone specigy it. NSLog of a date used the 'NSDate` `description` method that defaults to GMT (UTC).

Comment: @zaph Im just checking I understand, if I log an NSDate object it defaults to GMT yes?How would you check to see if the date is GMT+1 when logging?

Comment: An NSDate is a moment of time, it can not be "GMT+1" or "GMT+anything".

Comment: It is the `description` method of `NSDate`  that uses a date formatter that uses GMT. The date does not change, the internal representation is always in GMT. Note: The Apple documentations refers to GMT, not UTC so I use GMT even  though it is archaic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate is an absolute moment of time, it does not have a timezone. The date object you have is correct: it is exactly the moment that code was executed.

If you need string representation of that moment of time in a specific time zone, use `stringFromDate:` just like you did.

If you need to know number values of hour/minute in a specific time zone, use `-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:]`.

```
[calendar setTimeZone:...];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

The date formatter defaults to the local timezone. If you want a different timezone specify it. `NSLog` of a date used the 'NSDatedescription` method that defaults to GMT (UTC).

Examining the code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
// Creates today's data in GMT (UTC) All NSDates are referenced to GMT.

NSLog(@"NSDate %@",today); (moved up for explanation ordering)
// NSDate 2015-07-01 16:07:22 +0000
// Displays the date in GMT

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
// Creates a date for matter with the system timezone

NSLog(@"Time %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]);
// Time 2015-07-01 17:07:22

// Creates a string representation in the system timezone and displays it
NSDate*stringDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
// Creates a date from the string taking into the system timezone
NSLog(@"Time date %@",stringDate);

// Time date 2015-07-01 16:07:22 +0000
// Displays the date in GMT.
```